# Angular 5 Creating Page Loading From Extreme Amounts Of Data

Tags: angular

Say a service call brings back 1000 pieces of data (like an array with 1000 pieces). Is there a way to limit ngFor or the get call for the first 1-100 items, then on a click load the next 101-200 pieces, etc. But that data piece needs to reload, so if you make a change to piece 256, then it should reload items 201-300, not reload items 1-1000 and then only display 201-300

Comment: can you add some code if you have started something already, there are so many ways this can be done

Comment: @Obed7 I don't have anything written yet. Just trying to figure what can be done, especially if Angular has an answer to this